# How to check whether the Home button is pressed in iPhone and act accordingly?

Tags: iphone, ios, home-button

I want to show an alert when a user taps the Home button. I tried with:

- `applicationWillResignActive`
- `applicationDidEnterBackground`
- `applicationWillEnterForeground`
- `applicationWillTerminate`

... but nothing worked. For the first three, the alert comes when the application comes back to foreground from background. I want to show the alert immediately after Home button is pressed. Is there any way to do this?

Also: I want to run the app in foreground itself, or send to background as per user input.

Comment: You cannot change or override the home button functionality..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, You can't do that. The home button functionality is not accessible via any event handlers in Objective C.

You only get "notified" by the UIApplicationDelegate whenever the app is resigned from being active or becomes active, but you can't display any alerts there since you can't *lock* the home button or make the user wait for an alert for the home button to work.

In summation, The home button must always go home, It doesn't matter what your application wants or needs :)

Comment: Thanks.. i shud go 4 an alternative nw.. :(

Comment: There's no alternative unfortunately . You can't override the home button. If my answer helped I would appreciate it if you marked it as the right answer ;)

Comment: sure. i ws waiting to complete 7 mins so that I can mark it.. alternative - I mean any other ways to alert the user.. thats it. not with home btn functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry It cant  be achieved .

The methods you mentioned happens after the button press event but it cannot stop the event of home button